# Can Gmail messages be archived via the API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

It doesn't appear to be possible to archive mail using the API. Archiving in the web interface involves *moving*, rather than *labeling* a message to "All Mail". Not only is there no "All Mail" label listed by the API, but `move` is missing as well. There is only `modify` and this allows only adding or removing labels from a message. This is strange, because the docs say it's possible to "[Create filters to automatically label, forward, or archive messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)". Additionally, the `filters` `action` API includes only `forward`, `addLabelIds` and `removeLabelIds`.

Is there something I'm not seeing, yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check the documentation [filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#actions)  it appears that you need to remove the label `INBOX`

```
action.removeLabelIds=['INBOX']
```

Comment: I thought of that. But messages in the inbox don't appear to have the `INBOX` label. I could be wrong as I haven't checked this in the API. But they don't seem to in the web interface.

Comment: Well its documented i suggest you try it :)  There is a difference between the web interface and the API.