# How to get ID of newly sent gmail message through GMAIL api with PHP and delete or archive this message

Tags: php, gmail-api

I would like to know how I can retrieve the ID of a newly sent email through Gmail api and delete or archive it.

Here's my code for the Gmail api:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

    $fromemail = "some@mail.com";
    $strRawMessage = "From: from name <$fromemail> \r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "To: ".$CONTACTS_FNAME." ".$CONTACTS_LNAME." <$RECIPIENT>\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($EMAILSUBJECT) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "$EMAILBODY\r\n";
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

Comment: There's a code sample here to get ID in php:https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send
in regards to archiving, not sure there's an actual endpoint or method in the API for it but this might help ya;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701092/can-gmail-messages-be-archived-via-the-api

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the ID of your messages using [`Users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list). The response will be something like this, where `users.messages Resource` will contain the `id`:

```
{
  "messages": [
    users.messages Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

To delete messages, you may use either:

- [`Users.messages.delete`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete#php), which **permanently** deletes messages and cannot be undone;
- [`Users.messages.trash`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/trash), which **moves messages to trash** instead; or
- Use [filtering](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings#actions) to add the `TRASH` label on your messages: `action.addLabelIds=['TRASH']`

As for archiving, you can use [Filtering](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings). Filters can automatically add or remove labels or forward emails to verified aliases based on the attributes or content of the incoming message. If you want the messages to be out of your inbox and archived directly to one of your specific labels, you need to **remove** the `INBOX` label.

```
action.removeLabelIds=['INBOX']
```